# Using the languagefile to populate the "ok" button for the AlertDialog in Android using Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

So I tried creating an alertDialog, with an OK button coming from the language file, but when I do that, it fails to render the button using this code.

```
var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
    message: L('timeoutErrorMessage'),
    title: L('timeoutErrorTitle'),
    ok: L('okButton')
})
```

Same story when I use `buttonNames`, and even with `okid`

```
var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
    message: L('timeoutErrorMessage'),
    title: L('timeoutErrorTitle'),
    buttonNames: [L('okButton')]
});
```

But when I plainly put in the text, it works fine:

```
var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
    message: L('timeoutErrorMessage'),
    title: L('timeoutErrorTitle'),
    buttonNames: ['Okay'] // (or ok: 'Okay')
});
```

How can I get it to work using the language file?

Comment: Can not you set a variable and use it? var m = Ti.Locale.getString('timeoutErrorMessage', 'noTimeoutTranslation'); var dialog... message: m,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can't use the i18n functions with AlertDialog at this time. There are a few relevant tickets, which I encourage you to watch (more watchers == higher priority during triaging).

There's an Alloy-specific ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/ALOY-853 but it is probably just a manifestation of the related SDK ticket https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-14763

There's also https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-17205 covering a parity difference between how iOS & Android handle missing or invalid i18n key names. Titanium on iOS outputs the key name if missing/invalid; Android outputs an empty string. So, the button is probably there as a result of your code, just with no text and therefore invisible.